# Alterar Senha de SA do SQL SERVER com Conta de Admin do Windows

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, segurança

Recebi uma máquina com uma instância do SQL Server 2008 instalada, consigo acessar essa instância através do SQL Server Management Studio Express com minha conta de administrador do Windows mas não consigo executar nenhum ação dentro da instância devido ao fato de não ter permissão.

1 - Consigo alterar a senha ou excluir a conta de SA com a conta de ADMIN do Windows?

2 - Consigo dar permissão de `sysadmin` para a conta ADMIN do Windows sem usar a conta de SA?

Comment: o user SA está habilitado?

Comment: Sim está Habilitado, o SA é o único sysadmin da instância, e o usuário perdeu a senha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cara, eu já fiz isso uma vez. Segui os passos detalhados neste artigo:
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/22044-recover-sa-password-on-microsoft-sql-server

Em resumo, a ideia é dar um start no serviço como usuário único.
O caminho é o seguinte:

1. Dar um stop no serviço do SQL Server
2. Alterar a linha de comando do serviço do SQL Server para adicionar opção '-m'
3. Iniciar novamente o serviço (agora com este comando)
4. Abrir o `sqlcmd` com seu usuário e executar:

   ```
   EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember 'DOMAIN\Username', 'sysadmin';
   GO
   ```
5. Dê um stop de novo no serviço, retire a opção `-m` e reinicie o serviço
6. Você terá acesso para resetar a senha do SA

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, funcionou!

Answer (score -1):

Cara foi massa para mim funcionou quando fiz a alteração da senha via cmd
Dar um stop no serviço do SQL Server
Alterar a linha de comando do serviço do SQL Server para adicionar opção '-m'

via DOS executar sqlcmd -S WIN-D0NTN4PVBFS\SQLEXPRESS
go
sp_password @old = null, @new = 'rohto17@', @loginame = 'sa'
go
valeu